# Add an external configuration file in Vue for deployment?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, config

I have to call an API (json-server) to retrieve data in order to populate my dropdowns within my Vue application. Instead of hard-coding within the app, I want to create an external configuration file where I can put any links and eventually put server details for deployment. Currently, I have this but for some reason when I reference the Key in my vue component, it says it undefined. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
    /public/config.json
    
   {
     "API_URL": "localhost:3000"
   }
```

Here is the relevant parts of the main.js file:

```
    /main.js

    fetch(process.env.BASE_URL+ "config.json")
    .then((json) => {
    json().then((config) => {
    Vue.prototype.$config = config
    new Vue({
     router,
     store,
     render: (h) => h(App)
   }).$mount("#app")
  })
 })
```

In my Vue component, I'm trying to reference it like this, but it is showing up as undefined.

```
      <script>
      export default {
      mounted() {
        fetch(this.$config.API_URL)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.mailboxes = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
      }
      }

      </script>
```

If there is another way to go about this please let me know.

Comment: i think `.env` file is the solution, just make sure that he is added in your .gitignore, for more detais check the [officiel doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the app build once and use same bundle on multiple servers with different configuration, this is right way to do it. [ENV variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) suggested in comments wont work as the values are "baked in" to the bundle...

However you are using `fetch` in a wrong way. `fetch` returns [response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which you are trying to call instead of calling `response.json()`

```js
fetch(process.env.BASE_URL+ "config.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((config) => {
    Vue.prototype.$config = config
    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: (h) => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app")
  })
```

Comment: I'm running into an issue where in the fetch code above it says "BASE_URL" is undefined and on the fourth line $config is unused. In my Vue component when I use fetch(this.$config.API_URL), it says API_URL is an unresolved variable. Do I have to define it elsewhere?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Is this Vue CLI project? Sounds like errors from Vetur/ESLint, not actual runtime errors...