# Vue.js - want to lazy load config.json, instead of including at compile time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, config

I'm trying to create a file like the appsettings in a web.config in my vue app, that my vue app can use to load config info at runtime that changes form one deployment level to another (dev/qa/prod)

I'm loading it thusly

Vue.prototype.$config = require('/public/config.json')

but when I look at the transpiled output, it has the values of the file loaded in and hardcoded, not code to load from the file

in app90117256.js: (and js.map)

```
t.exports = JSON.parse('{""name":"value" etc.....
```

How do I get it to load the file at runtime instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the config at runtime, do not use build time constructs, which `require` or `import` (or [Vue CLI ENV variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)) are...

Options:

1. use either [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XHR_(XMLHttpRequest)) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) browser API to request the json file from the server during ([or before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68546717/381282)) your app starts
2. transform the json into JS file which assigns some global variable (`window.appConfig` for example), load it using `<script>` placed in `index.html` (before your app bundle) and then access it using `window.appConfig` from the app